# Regex - Python: Capture three (3) words after a specific word

Tags: python, regex

Hello everyone I have the following code:

```
str1 =  "Hello, I would like to meet you at the train station of Berlin after 6 o' clock"
match = re.compile(r' at \w+ \w+ \w+')
match.findall(str1)
```

Is there a better way than "\w+ \w+ \w" so for example to capture specific number of words?

Comment: Why not just `str.split` into words then slice from the index of the word you're looking for? Why use regex at all?

Comment: yeap this is indeed a way, but I wanted regex solution kinda. Thank you very much for the proposal though!

Comment: the answer you have given is regex one..what else do you want?

Comment: anyway, there was a Mr X that posted this     

match = re.compile(r'(at (?:(?:\w+(?:\s+|$)){5}))')

and it is exactly what I am looking for

Comment: Yes, there is a better way. Use `nltk` and its tokenizers to make a *list* of words, then find `at` and slice the list following it.

Comment: Thank you but I am focusing on regex

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. To specify a particular count for the match, use curly-braces. E.g.,:

```
match = re.compile(r'at ((\w+ ){3})')
```

Which gives:

```
>>> print match.findall(str1)
[('the train station ', 'station ')]
```

In general, to capture just the `n` words after `word`, your regex would be:

```
'word\s+((?:\w+(?:\s+|$)){n})'
```

Where `?:` designates a "non-capturing" group, `\s` designates whitespace, `|` means "or", and `$` means "end of string". Therefore:

```
>>> print re.compile(r'at\s+((?:\w+(?:\s+|$)){3})').findall(str1)
['the train station ']
```

Comment: Nice! Even better than:

    match = re.compile(r'(at (?:(?:\w+(?:\s+|$)){5}))')

Thanks a lot!

Comment: @D1W1TR15 Actually, the solution you just quoted contains at least one important improvement: the group `(?:\s+|$)`. This allows the match to work even at the end of a string, where `\s+` won't match, since it means "one or more whitespace characters". I am going to include it in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation though ~ I am kind of experimenting. Another great step for Regex has been made! :)